# How to make Partitions AutoMount and show up in filesystem (/media/userName)?

Tags: partitioning, mount, automount, dropbox

I am trying to sync Dropbox to one of my drives. However, I am unable to set custom download folder to a drive of my choice.

The drive that I am trying to sync with can be viewed by file browser. But unable to even locate it via 'Find Directory' dialog that dropbox shows.

I can see 2 of my 7 drives at,

```
/media/<user>
```

I need the Drive to be mounted at startup.

My fstab looks like this,

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=d905892a-7c46-4b89-b31b-93f722a5ace6 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=8d9b1ec4-970d-4d01-920a-2c718623279f none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/E6BAF689BAF65591 /mnt/E6BAF689BAF65591 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D31BB96C8101D0 /mnt/01D31BB96C8101D0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D315D7FEDD8A40 /mnt/01D315D7FEDD8A40 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/01D31BC1EA039DE0 /mnt/01D31BC1EA039DE0 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0
```

Drive properties from Disks,

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to mount your file system in a specific location to use it with Dropbox. You merely need a fixed location which you probably already have. Should this not be the case, write a comment.

You said you can find the mount point via Nautilus. Simply navigate there, then press <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd>. This will show you a text field containing the path of the current location.

Open you Dropbox path configuration, then click on `Computer` on the left. You will see a slash. Click on it, then navigate where the path in Nautilus tells you to. Press `Choose` when you're done.